# Drizzle ORM - decimal MySQL is a string?

Tags: typescript, drizzle

The schema:

```
export const myTable = mysqlTable(
  "MyTable",
  {
    id: varchar("id", { length: 191 }).notNull(),
    value: decimal("value", { precision: 7, scale: 4 }).notNull(),
    createdAt: datetime("createdAt", { mode: "date" })
      .default(sql`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`)
      .notNull(),
  },
  (table) => {
    return {
      myTableId: primaryKey(table.id),
    };
  }
);
```

The code:

```
type MyTable = InferModel<typeof myTable, "select">;

const values: MyTable[] = await db.select().from(myTable);
```

The type of `values[0].value` is `string`, and I figure it should be a `number`.

I could not find anything related to this on Drizzle docs, Github Issues or StackOverflow, and I would like to understand why this happens, or, if I'm making any mistakes.

EDIT: I added an answer that "fixes" the type, but does not answer why `double` becomes a `number` and `decimal` becomes a `string`, which is enough for me.

EDIT 2: Thanks @ColouredPanda and @andrew-allen: https://github.com/drizzle-team/drizzle-orm/issues/570#issuecomment-1646033240

Comment: Javascript's `number` does not support the precision as required by mysql's decimal type. To not lose data, its read as a string

Comment: I know they do this on purpose for numeric (postgres) due to precision

Comment: @ColouredPanda is this the official answer from Drizzle? That sounds like reasonable, I just want to be sure.

Comment: @AlanSikora it will be e.g. https://github.com/drizzle-team/drizzle-orm/issues/570#issuecomment-1646033240

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not be an answer to the "why decimals become strings", but it answers the typing problem, which was my main concern.

Instead of `decimal`, use `double`. Drizzle will automatically infer `double` to `number`.

The updated schema:

```
export const myTable = mysqlTable(
  "MyTable",
  {
    id: varchar("id", { length: 191 }).notNull(),
    value: double("value", { precision: 7, scale: 4 }).notNull(),
    createdAt: datetime("createdAt", { mode: "date" })
      .default(sql`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`)
      .notNull(),
  },
  (table) => {
    return {
      myTableId: primaryKey(table.id),
    };
  }
);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try any of the ff.:

**1**. Customize [column data type](https://orm.drizzle.team/docs/column-types/mysql#customizing-column-data-type). Converts the typescript data type into a number, but you'll still get a string as a result:

```
{
  value: decimal('value', { precision: 7, scale: 4 }).$type<number>().notNull()
}
```

**2**. [Custom types](https://orm.drizzle.team/docs/custom-types) to make the data type a number, and also accept/return a number:

```
import { customType, mysqlTable, int } from 'drizzle-orm/mysql-core';

const decimalNumber = customType<{ data: number }>({
  dataType() {
    return 'decimal(7, 4)';
  },
  fromDriver(value) {
    return Number(value);
  },
});

export const myTable = mysqlTable('MyTable', {
  id: varchar('id', { length: 191 }).notNull(),
  value: decimalNumber('value').notNull(),
});
```

**3**. Use double.

Be aware that JavaScript number is a 64-bit floating point value, so at some point, you wind up losing precision (why Drizzle end up using strings for decimals).

Comment: 1 and 2 solution seems to break `db.insert()` typescript when using `createInsertSchema()` via drizzle-zod, at least at the moment of this writing

Comment: @arvil good to know that issue. I might try drizzle-zod one day and report back to you.

Answer (score 1):

What I've done to workaround this is adding type assertion like this:

```js
export const db = mysqlTable("someDb", {
  weight: decimal("weight", {
    precision: 6, scale: 2
  }) as unknown as MySqlDoubleBuilderInitial<"weight">
});
```

In this way, I still can use DECIMAL SQL type (which is what I really want) and typescript types works correctly in all my code base (weight is `number`).
I think is safe to do this type assertion because when I check `typeof weight` it returns `"number"` and (I believe) that javascript number supports my specified precision

Comment: Instead of asserting the type like that, you can do `decimal('weight').$type<number>()` instead